# How to customise the look of the PFSignUpViewController

Tags: swift, parse-platform

If you are using PFLogInViewController with the PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton option enabled how do you customise the look of the PFSignUpViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass `PFSignUpViewController`, and perform your layout customisations in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
class SpuggySignUpViewController: PFSignUpViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Customisation here
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // More customisation here
  }

}
```

To get your custom version of `PFSignUpViewController` presented by the `PFLoginViewController`, just instantiate it, and set it in the `PFLoginViewController`.

```
let loginController = PFLoginViewController()
let customSignupController = SpuggySignUpViewController()
loginController.signUpController = customSignupController
// Now show your login Controller
```